# Best way to get first not null value using optionals in Java

Tags: java, option-type

We have code like this:

```
String tempDir = SwingInstanceManager.getInstance().getTempFolderPath(clientId);
if (tempDir == null) {
    tempDir = System.getProperty(Constants.TEMP_DIR_PATH);
    if (tempDir == null) {  
            tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")).toURI().toString();
    }
}
```

I want to remove brackets, so if it was only 2 values I'd write like this:

```
String tempDir = Optional.ofNullable(SwingInstanceManager.getInstance().getTempFolderPath(clientId)).orElse(System.getProperty(Constants.TEMP_DIR_PATH));
```

But is there any way to write such chain for 3+ values?(withount using second optional in orElse call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your second option is actually a property, you can rely on the `getProperty(String, String)` method rather than just `getProperty(String)`:

```
String tempDir = Optional.ofNullable(SwingInstanceManager.getInstance().getTempFolderPath(clientId))
                         .orElse(System.getProperty(Constants.TEMP_DIR_PATH,
                                                    new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")).toURI().toString());
```

Though I'd recommend using `Path` rather than `File` in that latter part (`Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")).toURI().toString()`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ordered `List` and pick the first non-null item from it.

```
String[] tempSourcesArray = {null, "firstNonNull", null, "otherNonNull"};
List<String> tempSourcesList = Arrays.asList(tempSourcesArray);
Optional firstNonNullIfAny = tempSourcesList.stream().filter(i -> i != null).findFirst();
System.out.println(firstNonNullIfAny.get()); // displays "firstNonNull"
```

Comment: but that increases amount of code, instead of decreasing it :(

Comment: Well really it's just the one line `list.stream().filter(i=>i!=null).findFirst()` the rest is here so it works as a standalone. Also it would be better for a number of sources > 5 I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static <T> T firstNotNull(Supplier<T>... values) {
    for (Supplier<T> e : values) {
        T value = e.get();
        if (value != null)
            return value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and

```
String tempDir = firstNotNull(
    () -> SwingInstanceManager.getInstance().getTempFolderPath(clientId),
    () -> System.getProperty(Constants.TEMP_DIR_PATH),
    () -> new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")).toURI().toString());
```